# Table layout in android -Row sizing

Tags: android

I have a table layout as shown.I have a lot of rows.
I have used android:strechcolumns="1" to strech the second column of each row.This is the case everywhere.

But in the fifth row I have 2 fields.I want them to occupy equal space.The row size should be same as that of the previous row.I want the overall size of the rows to remain the same as that on the screeshot.Also I have indicated in the screenshot the boundary within which all rows should lie .

How can this be done?

```
<TableRow>
    <TextView
        android:gravity="right"
        android:paddingTop="10dip"
        />
    <Spinner
    android:id="@+id/depot_name_spinner"/>
</TableRow>

<TableRow>
    <TextView 
     android:text="@string/product_name"
     android:paddingTop="10dip"
     android:gravity="right"/>
    <Spinner
    android:id="@+id/product_name_spinner"
     />
</TableRow>

<TableRow>
    <TextView
        android:text="@string/date"
        android:gravity="right" />
    <Button
    android:id="@+id/date_button" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow>
    <TextView 
        android:text="@string/measure_ltr"
        android:gravity="right"

        />
    <EditText
    android:id="@+id/ltr_text" 
    android:layout_width="50dip"/>
     <TextView 
        android:text="@string/measure_qts"
        android:gravity="right"
     />
      <EditText

    android:id="@+id/qts_text"
     />  
</TableRow>
```

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add not only `TableRow` to the table. Just use a simple `LinearLayout` and put all raw content into it. I think it must solve your problem.

**EDIT**: Also, you can add the `LinearLayout` with all widgets to a `TableRow` and set `LinearLayout`'s `android:layout_span=2`:

```
<TableRow>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_span="2">
        <TextView 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/measure_ltr"
            android:gravity="right"/>
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/ltr_text" 
            android:layout_width="50dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/measure_qts"
            android:gravity="right"/>
        <EditText  
            android:id="@+id/qts_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</TableRow>
```

I haven't tried it, but hope it will work.

Comment: I am using that at the moment but not able to replicate the exact height of the previous row.Do you know the default dip size for the rows that i have constructed using strech columns in table row?

Comment: I don't know how to get `TableRow`'s default height. But I added another solution to the answer.

Comment: Checked out on the piece of code you gave me.It seems like android:span is not available for linear layout.I checked out the docs .It's not there.The xml is giving me an error.

Comment: It worked for me using the linear layout inside the table row.Can you remove the code so that i can accept your answer

Comment: `android:layout_span` can be used inside a table row, but its value must be in quotes. So it must be `android:layout_span="2"`. It was my mistake and I fixed it.

Comment: yes it works.But not exactly what i wanted.Anyway I have got it through linear layouts itself.Needed to tweak the dimensions.Thanks for your help.

Comment: And what's the problem with the span?

Answer (score 1):

Try using android:weight. This will divide the remaining space  once the layout is laid out in which ever way you want. I mean you can define the proportion of space which each of your view should use. Look into this example below.

```
<TableLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TableRow>

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:weightSum="100">     // Mention Weightsum as 100 so that its easy to split among your views.

        <TextView android:id="@+id/row1Label" 
            android:layout_width="0dip" android:layout_weight="60"      // This will occupy 60% of the remaining space
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </TextView>

        <TextView android:id="@+id/row1Label" 
            android:layout_width="0dip" android:layout_weight="40"      // This will occupy 40% of the remaining space
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </TextView>

    </LinearLayout>

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:weightSum="100">

        <TextView android:id="@+id/row2Label" 
            android:layout_width="0dip" android:layout_weight="60"      // This will occupy 60% of the remaining space
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </TextView>

        <TextView android:id="@+id/row3Label" 
            android:layout_width="0dip" android:layout_weight="40"      // This will occupy 40% of the remaining space
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </TextView>


        // You can more views and distribute the space accordingly....

    </LinearLayout>

    </TableRow>
```

...........

With this you can achieve something like this 
[image]

You can split the Table row area in whichever way you want. This can done using only Linear Layout as other layouts don't have this options of weights. I have used this methodology extensively to create complex views. Hope it helps you.